# Convert time and date to timestamp

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, datetime

I have the following date:

```
Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

How I can convert it to timestamp?

case:

```
'Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'::timestamp
```

doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with the entire string as given:

```
select  to_timestamp('Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)', 'Dy Mon DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS GMT TZH')::timestamp;

to_timestamp     
---------------------
 2020-09-16 07:23:49
```

I'm in `PDT` so the time got rotated to that.

For more information on `to_timestamp` and the meaning of the elements of the format string, see here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Just `cast()`!

```
select cast('Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000' as timestamp)
select 'Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000'::timestamp
```

Or, if you prefer to generate a `timestamp with time zone`:

```
select cast('Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000' as timestamp with time zone)
select 'Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000'::timestamp with time zone
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d20facce4b4e8b430ca28966e23f9973)**

Answer (score 0):

A simple conversion works:

```
select 'Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000'::timestamp
```

Or if you want the timezone:

```
select 'Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000'::timestamptz
```

You can just take the initial portion:

```
select left('Wed Sep 16 2020 14:23:49 GMT+0000', 33)::timestamp
```

Comment: it fails, becouse there is also (Coordinated Universal Time)

Comment: @Ted . . . You can use string operations to convert the first 33 characters.